# Spark: How to convert a String to multiple columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe that contains a field item which is a string having a array of items:

```
[{"item":"76CJMX4Y"},{"item":"7PWZVWCG"},{"item":"967NBPMS"},{"item":"72LC5SMF"},{"item":"8N6DW3VD"},{"item":"045QHTU4"},{"item":"0UL4MMSI"}]

root
 |-- item: string (nullable = true)
```

I would like to get the item as array of string. Can someone let me know if there is a easy way to do this with default from_json ?

root
|-- item: array (nullable = true)

So that I will only have

```
["76CJMX4Y", "7PWZVWCG", "967NBPMS", "72LC5SMF", "8N6DW3VD", "045QHTU4", "0UL4MMSI"]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Spark built-in functions [**`from_json`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/sql/#from_json) and then use higher order function **`transform`** to extract item from the array.

## Example

```
//from_json we are creating a json array then extracting item from the array
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._


df.selectExpr("""transform(from_json(item,'array<struct<item:string>>'),x->x.item) as item""").show(10,false)

//+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|item                                                                  |
//+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|[76CJMX4Y, 7PWZVWCG, 967NBPMS, 72LC5SMF, 8N6DW3VD, 045QHTU4, 0UL4MMSI]|
//+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use split() on :, then sort with sort_array() the values (so that the values you’re not interested in are either at the top or bottom, then filter using slice().

For your reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html (even if it’s the Java version, it’s the synthetic list of functions).